# Why infinite slider is lag when complete 1 round?

Tags: html, css

My infinite slider is lag when it complete a round
here is codepen :
https://codepen.io/ijithaky-the-flexboxer/pen/wvjKPRq

```
@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(calc(-150px * 10));
  }
}
@keyframes scroll-2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(calc(-150px * 10));
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include the full example in a snippet in the question. An external link is fine as an additional resource, but the code must be in the body question. (Also, your codepen doesn't seem to display any "infinite slider" for me)

Comment: Nothing seems to be scrolling in your codepen. Please put all the relevant code direct into your question, not on an external site, and make it into a runnable snippet and ensure it will show us the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing this.

Comment: The codepen is incomplete. Please provide a testable code in your question.

Comment: sorry guy, i fixed it in codepen